bash script directory of flac files to array produces strange results
I'm working on a project to manage my FLAC music files, and organize them into directories by the artist name. I am using metaflac to obtain the files' meta and getting the artist value, and then I want to create (if not exist) a directory using the artist name value and move the file into that directory.
I want to load the filenames of a specified directory (arg) into an array, and iterate that array to get the file's metaflac information. My script is almost working, but the filenames values are showing with newlines in the filenames.
One other thing, this will be happening on a mounted USB drive ie; media/scott/usbstick. This is my current script which is running on my ~/Music/ directory, however I don't think it matters where I run it.
echo "You entered: '${*-}'"

(
if [ ! -d "$1" ]
then
   echo "Arg "$1" is NOT a directory!"
   exit
fi

flacfiles=`ls -l "$1"*.flac`

for filename in $flacfiles
do 

echo "$filename";

   # pull the artist=name string from flac
   #  s=`metaflac --show-tag=ARTIST "$file"`
   #  get the artist on the right of the = sign
   #  artist=$(echo "$s" | cut -d'=' -f2)

   #  echo " Creating folder $artist and moving $file into it"

   #  create dir of the artist, if not already exists
   #  mkdir -p "$artist"
   #  move the file into the artist directory
   #  mv "$file" "$artist"


done
} 

And my output looks like this
scott@minty-fresh:~/Music$ ./process.sh Oplayers/
You entered: 'Oplayers/'
Oplayers/Dance
(If
Ya
Wanta).flac
Oplayers/Everybody
Loves
The
Sunshine.flac
Oplayers/Fight
Me,
Chase
Me.flac

The desired output for each $filename is a single line. metaflac is complaining it cannot find the file, probably because of the newlines in the $filename.

Try flacfiles=("$1"/*) then for filename in "${flacfiles[@]}"...
